# How to remove an item from listbox with datasource set, using string in C#

Tags: c#, listbox, arraylist, listboxitem

refferring to [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx)

how can I remove an item using string???
(I don't want to remove it by using selected index)
I want something like

```
USStates.Remove("Alabama","AL");
```

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the selected item or a particular item?  It's unclear from your example what the type of the underlying object is.  Understanding this is necessary to answer how to remove a value

Comment: a particular item, without selecting any item of the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: I assume you add a button that you can click to remove an item.

```
    BindingList<USState> USStates;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        USStates = new BindingList<USState>();
        USStates.Add(new USState("Alabama", "AL"));
        USStates.Add(new USState("Washington", "WA"));
        USStates.Add(new USState("West Virginia", "WV"));
        USStates.Add(new USState("Wisconsin", "WI"));
        USStates.Add(new USState("Wyoming", "WY"));

        listBox1.DataSource = USStates;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "LongName";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "ShortName";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var removeStates = (from state in USStates
                            where state.ShortName == "AL"
                            select state).ToList();
        removeStates.ForEach( state => USStates.Remove(state) );
    }
```

PS: I thought you're using WPF in my previous answer.

Comment: Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection does not contain a definition for "GetItemAt"

Comment: See above. You can do without setting the data source to null.

Comment: Ah, Thank you. Your previous answer just works fine after I modified it a bit. I replaced the ".GetItemAt(i)" with only "[i]". And this answer works like a miracle too! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `Items` collection but you can change the DataSource (List or ArrayList).

First of all override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` methods in `USState` type.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
     return myLongName.GetHashCode() + myShortName.GetHashCode();
} 
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
     return GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

Now, you can remove an element,

```
 listBox1.DataSource = null; // Set null so you can update DataSource
 USStates.Remove(new USState("Wisconsin", "WI"));
 listBox1.DataSource = USStates;
 listBox1.DisplayMember = "LongName";
 listBox1.ValueMember = "ShortName";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use an ArrayList, use a List. Then you can remove based on whatever the type T is,

```
    list.Remove("whatever");
```

Comment: I need to use the array list to add display and value member to the listbox